# Encrypting video file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am encrypting video file stored in assets folder, but getting the following error:

```
FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = 'video123enc.aes' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30))
```

This is code i implemented:

```
encryptFile() async {
  File inFile = new File("assets/video123.mp4");
  File outFile = new File("video123enc.aes");

  bool outFileExists = await outFile.exists();

  if(!outFileExists){
    await outFile.create();
  }

  final videoFileContents = await inFile.readAsStringSync(encoding: latin1);

  final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('HInsowjHDYEuwksmDuWhCkslowhdUJMQWi');
  final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(videoFileContents, iv: iv);
  await outFile.writeAsBytes(encrypted.bytes);
  print("done");
}
```

The error is seen when creating the `outFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. You can either edit AndroidManifest.xml and add the following line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Else you can use Flutter [Permission Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/permission)